# How to use redis database with django?

Tags: django, django-models, redis

I am planning to store all my user activity logs( like user logged in, password changed etc)in a redis database instead of the main database used in the project.

For example:

```
class MyLogModel(models.Model):
  log_msg = models.CharField(..)
```

Then I usually create the table like this

```
MyLogModel.objects.create(log_msg='msg')
```

My question is can I do the same with Redis?

If not redis how can I optimize my database with django since over the time it will have so many data which might make the database slower.

OR another option deleting the activity logs older than 1 month something like this would be better ?
OR Is there any better approach for this scenario ?

Comment: How many log rows are you expecting to have in one month?

Comment: With good indexes even millions of rows can be fast to query

Comment: @IainShelvington then i think i can use the same database for the logs also ?

Comment: @D_P yes of course, you just need to add indexes for the the queries that you will make

Comment: @IainShelvington yes sure thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Selcuk not sure but i was confused having separate database like redis would be better for better performance for storing data like logs so

Comment: If you are dealing with less than a few million rows don't bother. It's not worth maintaining a second database. Even then there are better choices than redis for storing logs, such as ELK.